# Shell script detecting running in Cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, unix, shell, cygwin

Is there a simple way to check if a script is running in Cygwin. We have a script that calls a utility that expects the paths passed to be windows so if we're in Cygwin we have to convert the paths to windows paths.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `uname` utility. From [uname(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uname):

> -o, --operating-system
>     print the operating system

Example code:

```
if [ `uname -o` = "Cygwin" ]
then
    # Cygwin specific stuff
else
    # Other UNIX (Linux, etc.) specific stuff
fi
```

Comment: But [OS X's uname(1)](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/uname.1.html) (BSD uname) does not support the `-o` flag.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't recommend using `-o` if you need to be super portable, too many flavors of *nix don't recognize it.  Some combination of `-s` and `-r` should do the trick, and those flags have been around since the dawn of time.

Answer (score 3):

This works with ksh and bash.

```
#!/bin/ksh
case "$(uname -s)" in
    CYGWIN*) echo This is Cygwin ;;
    *) echo This is not Cygwin ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

check the output of `uname`utility

Answer (score 1):

Combining some of the comments and removing deprecated backticks results in:

```
#!/bin/bash
OS_NAME=$(uname -s)
OS_NAME=${OS_NAME:0:6}

if [[ "$OS_NAME" = "CYGWIN" ]]
then
    # Cygwin specific stuff
else
    # Other UNIX (Linux, etc.) specific stuff
fi
```